# Is this an example of recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

I am implementing inheritance of something called Contexts. Each Context holds a link to its parent context. If that Context is the root Context, its parent is null.

In order to walk up the inheritance tree and get the data from each Context, I want to do this (in pseudocode)

```
private Hashtable getDataAsMap() {
    Hashtable map  =  this.parent != null  ?  
                          this.parent.getDataAsMap()  :  
                          new Hashtable();

    // add my data

    return map;

}
```

Is this recursion? I'm calling the same method, but on a different object. Does that still count? If not, what would you call it?

Comment: yeah that is recursion, though more specifically here it can be called delegation

Comment: It's a recursive call only if `this.parent` is an object of the same type as `this`, so the same method is called. I know you said that both objects are instances of Context, but it's conceivable that `this` or `this.parent` is a subclass of Context and therefore may have a different implementation of `getDataAsMap()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  This satisfies the two criteria for a recursive algorithm:

1. An algorithm that takes 1 or more parameters and calls itself with a simplified version of the parameter(s) and
2. A base case that tells the algorithm where to stop recursing.

However, this looks like an odd way to do this.  It keeps looking up the tree until finding a root node (a node with no parent), and then returns a new object that's not actually associated with any of the nodes.  The end result will be identical to saying `return new Hashtable();`, but slower.  Are you sure that's what you intended?

Comment: So the fact that it's calling itself on a different object makes no difference?

Comment: yes - it is. It will return a hashtable with the data from all the nodes in the tree, with each later generation overwriting the data that it shares with its parent.

Comment: Well, yeah because you're calling the same function but with a different `this` pointer

Comment: @Chama: The "object it's calling on" is actually a parameter to the function.  The compiler essentially changes `foo.bar(1)` to `bar(foo, 1)`.  It's a basic part of the object-oriented model.  So yeah, this is an example of classic recursion; only the syntax is different.

Comment: @MasonWheeler I see. I forgot about the compiler change. Interesting.

Comment: @Matt: Yeah.  With the explanation, it makes sense now.

Comment: #2 is not a requirement to be recursive. Think about a main-loop done in a recursive style where the author didn't bother adding the exit case and expects you to ctrl+c to exit. It's not a good approach, but it is still classified as "recursive"

Comment: @chama the compiler does not "change" anything, it's just syntax. But if it's easier to think about it that way, sure.

Comment: @Jimmy: That's not classical recursion, though. That's using recursion as a "magic hammer" and trying to shoehorn it into a situation where a loop would be more appropriate.

Comment: Requirement 1 are actually 2 requirements, and the second of them is actually not a requirement for recursion. Most generally, it is recursion if the thing that is being defined is referenced, directly or not, in its own definition. (This way, one also captures recursive data types, etc.)

Comment: Hah, actually I was dead wrong. I wrote a diatribe here talking about the definition of the word then went to find a reference for it, and found the english definition which was as I expected, but then I found this definition from math http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_definition which actually says without rule #2 what you have is *circular* and for something to be *recursive* it needs to have base cases that do not self-reference. Learn something new every day :) Add that URL to your answer if you will, it's actually a great expanded explanation of recursion.

Comment: The other classic example is https://www.google.com/search?q=recursion